# Anomaly detection and explanation

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, anomaly-detection

I was given a dataset with 500 features which, after one-hot encoding, looks like this:

[image: dataset]

Class = 1 means "**anomaly**", class = 0 is "**normal**". So basically my task is simple ML classification. But another part of this task is to explain, why this data (which has class = 1) is anomalous. I wanted to build some graphs detect anomalies on pictures, but the problem is that one-hot encoding is used and I can't do anything about it.

I've started with using `feature_importances_`, but they don't give enough information specifically about class = 1.

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X,y)
plt.plot(rf.feature_importances_)
```

Could you please tell me, what statistic methods (or maybe something else) should I use to explain why some of my data are anomalous?

Comment: "So basically my task is simple ML classification." Actually, your task is [**anomaly detection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection). I cannot stress enough the difference between classification and anomaly detection. You will struggle a lot to build a classifier that performs well on an anomaly detection task, as I previously did. Please see my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/505368/296197) for an explanation.

Comment: Also, have you had a look at the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)?

Comment: @mhdadk, so basically you're idea is too use generative modelling in this case?

Comment: Yes. You could separate the dataset you have into two smaller datasets: one for class 1 (anomalous), and one for class 0 (non-anomalous). Given that the feature vectors in each sub-dataset are one-hot encoded, sum the vectors up in each dataset to form two histograms, where each bin corresponds to a feature. Normalize both histograms to form the probability distributions $p(X=x_i|C=1)$ and $p(X=x_i|C=0)$, where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ feature. Then choose the feature $x^*$ in each probability distribution that maximizes it. These features should explain the anomalous and non-anomalous data.

Comment: @mhdadk, what do you mean by "sum the vectors up"? where i can read more about that?

Comment: [1 0 0 1] + [1 0 1 0] = [2 0 1 1]

Comment: @oh... my bad. So technically i can do it for all my 500 features and then plot the histogram?

Comment: Yes. Try this and see what happens.

Comment: @mhdadk, thanks a lot !

Comment: For your ML model, did you use a random forest (or gbm, xgboost, etc.)? Those kind of models can work directly with category data, so it is better not to one-hot encode your inputs.  (If you used deep learning then your question still applies.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some libraries whereby you can get the SHAP values (SHapley Additive exPlanations) which explain the feature importance/influence for each class